# No muestra completo el texto GridControl DevExpress c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, devexpress

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con un gridcontrol ya que no me muestra completamente el texto de una celda pero cuando ubico el mouse cobre la celda si muestra el texto como mensaje y la verdad ya probe cambiandole todas las propiedades pero obtengo el mismo resultado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si el texto es más largo que el tamaño de la celda es claro que no se verá completo. O cambias el tamaño de la fuente del texto, o cambias el tamaño de la celda, o haces que el tamaño de la celda sea dinámico conforme al tamaño del texto

Comment: No es el tamaño si no que en el texto hay caracteres de salto de linea / asi como ese

Comment: Pues, si lo que dices es porque ya lo controlaste, usa un replaceAll en el string para reemplazar los \n por un espacio en blanco

Comment: @EminUrbina, Verifica que la propiedad `HorzScrollVisibility = Auto` este configurada como Auto o Always, prueba si esto resuelve tu problema. Al igual puedes revisar la propiedad `ColumnAutoWidth`

Comment: Probe con esas propiedades y de igual forma no evita el salto de texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolvi haciendo un reemplazo de esta forma desde sql

```
UPDATE Licitaciones
SET NombreArticulo = REPLACE(NombreArticulo, CHAR(10), '')
WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), NombreArticulo) > 0;
```